# How to access private variable of super class by using lombok SuperBuilder

Tags: java, inheritance, lombok

I have two class Parent and Child, where Parent and Child class has one variable with same name.

-> Parent class

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public class Parent {
    private String parentA;
    private String parentB;
    private String parentC;
}
```

-> Child Class

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public class Child extends  Parent {
    private String childA;
    private String parentB;  //variable name is same as Parent class
    private String childC;
}
```

Now in Main class I am making Child class object by using builder.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String Args[]) {

        Child child = Child.builder()
                .parentA() 
                .parentB()  // Here it is setting Child class variable
                .parentC()
                .childA()
                .childC()
                .build();
    }
 }
```

**Now I want to set parentB variable of parent class. Is there is any way to set it?**

Comment: Why don't you use setter for it ?

Comment: As parent and class has same variable name parentB, Lombok setter annotation will generate same function name to set variable (Here I can't edit parent class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@SuperBuilder` generates a method for each field defined in the annotated class, but not for fields from superclasses. Instead, the generated builder class `extends` the builder class of the superclass, so the methods for fields from superclasses are inherited from those builders.

If you have two exactly similar fields in `Parent` and `Child`, the method from `ChildBuilder` simply overrides the method from `ParentBuilder`. There is no way to call the method from `ParentBuilder` anymore (except for some ugly `MethodHandle` hacks, which you should not do).

Remark: Having two identical fields indicates that they have similar meaning. If this is the case, make one `protected` and remove the other. If they do not have the same meaning, naming them equally is a very bad idea and will almost certainly lead to bugs even if you do not use `@SuperBuilder`.